# Find filename using list inside a file

Tags: find, filenames

**How can i find all filenames that match a string in a list inside a file?**

I have a *list_file.txt* with a list of email addresses each in a new line like this:

```
1@mail.com
2@mail.com
3@mail.com
...
```

In the same directory i have many files that their filenames contains one of the email addresses of the list like this: *email_1@mail.com.txt*,      *email_2@mail.com.txt*, etc.

¿How can i copy all matching files to a new directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in $(cat list_file.txt) ; do
  cp "email_$i.txt" newdirectory/
done
```

or if you want each match to be copied to its own separate directory:

```
for i in $(cat list_file.txt) ; do
  mkdir -p email_$i
  cp "email_$i.txt" "email_$i/"
done
```